# How set one onclick listener on two different conditions?

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, onclicklistener, buttonclick

I have created a fragment in which I created a form which receive data from user. Then I send data to next fragment on button click.

In next fragment I have a edit button which pass arguments to previous fragment to edit data in form.

Now the issue is that I have two conditions in first fragment first one is to simply add data and second one is edit that data on receiving arguments. I have implemented an onclick listener on class level, and in click method I check whether my arguments is null.

If its null it simply moves to next fragment.if it have arguments then I will show previous data in fragment and user edit that data in fragment and then move to next fragment.

```java
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.candidReqNav:
                if (getArguments()!=null){
                  //edit previously added data and move to next fragment
                }
                else
                { 
                   //simply store data
                }
           }
     }
```

**How do I solve this?**